# Dynamic Elements

Tags: typo3, fluid

Is there a way to dynamically create elements in fluid like so:

```
<f:section name="foo">
  <{tag} />
</f:section>
```

what should be used somewhere like that:

```
<f:render section="foo" arguments="{ tag: 'f:form.textfield' }" />
```

what should result in output, containg: `<input type="text" … />`, not `<f:form.textfield … />` as it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like that, but you could do something with `f:switch`:

```
<f:section name="foo">
  <f:switch expression={tag}>
    <f:case value="f:form.textfield"><f:form.textfield /></f:case>
    <f:case value="etc">...</f:case>
  </f:switch>
</f:section>
```

Comment: Thanks… That is kind of a pity…